# Plotting SpatRaster objects changes the margin parameters in R, can I prevent this?

Tags: r

I'm not sure what exactly the culprit is (the SpatRaster class as such, or the size of the raster files, or what package is handling the plotting call — terra, I think), but I keep having this annoying issue: after plotting a raster object, the margin parameters for the plotting device are permanently changed such that the axis labels are outside the plotting window, and I have to either *dev.off()* or reset the parameters in order to fix it. What causes this, and can I fix it?

Example to show what I mean:

```
# Plotting some arbitrary data
plot(1)
```

[image: A plot with a single point, margins OK]

```
# Plotting a raster object
my_map <- geodata::elevation_30s("United Kingdom", path = "data")
terra::plot(my_map)
```

[image: An elevation map of the UK]

```
# For all subsequent plots, the margins have now been gobbled up:
plot(1)
```

[image: A plot with a single point, but the margins are reduced]

Comment: I do not see that. Are you using the current version of "terra"?

Comment: Yes, I just updated terra and am still having the same problem.

Comment: It would help if you edited your question and include a reproducible example. And run this in a clean session (no other packages loaded).

Comment: @RobertHijmans Sorry, yes, good point. I've replaced my example with a reproducible one. I'm running this with no packages loaded (except base, grDevices, methods, stats and utils).

The same problem occurs whether I'm in RStudio or in the default R GUI.

Comment: What is printed when you do `library(terra)`?

Comment: Only the version note, "terra 1.7.18"

Comment: The version on CRAN is 1.7-65, so you clearly are not using the current version. You are probably updating in RStudio. That often does not work well as it loads packages on startup. Update in a clean R session using command line or Rgui instead.

Comment: Yep, updating the package in Rgui fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else experiencing this problem, updating the *terra* package in the vanilla R GUI (i.e. while not using RStudio) fixed the issue.

Thank you to [Robert Hijmans](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/8993/robert-hijmans) for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

Neither I..

```r
plot(1)
```

[image]

```r
my_map <- geodata::elevation_30s("United Kingdom", path = "data")
terra::plot(my_map)
```

[image]

```r
plot(1)
```

[image]

```r
packageVersion("terra")
#> [1] '1.7.69'
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

But you can play with `par()` like:

```
oldpar <- par(no.readonly = TRUE)
...
terra::plot(my_map)
...
par(oldpar)
plot(1)
```

Comment: Reinstalled terra, it's still happening. This is very peculiar.